# Push floated image below text for smaller screens

Tags: css

quick question that's been bugging me and I cant work out how to do it. I'm wanting to have an image that's floated to the right of a paragraph of text. No problem, have got that working.

What I'm looking to do is push that image below the text for some of the media queries (say under 768px). I'm having issues doing this due to the image being the first element in the paragraph.

Thanks.

```css
img.right {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto
}
```

```html
<p><img class="right" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/matiasam/ios7-style/512/Clear-Tick-icon.png" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex cum utinam nullam equidem, eam an virtute antiopam molestiae. Cum expetendis necessitatibus ea. His iisque conceptam ea, vel novum maiorum ea. Has duis tempor at, quo no elit denique fastidii. Eam justo partiendo te. Diam clita detraxit in pri, copiosae accusata sadipscing te nec. Ad soleat quaerendum pro. Id eos causae eirmod, nec libris quidam commodo cu. Vis et vidit dicam. Ipsum eruditi erroribus eam in, eum lucilius sadipscing omittantur id, aliquam adolescens id nam. Ius deleniti constituam no. Ut dicam ridens pro, qui ea viris scriptorem. Sed ei dicam graeci regione, et placerat suscipiantur has. Solum ridens eu mel. Eius omittam ex per. Summo ancillae ex vim, eam eu case dicit, ei sale primis facete sea. An vix omittam accommodare. An usu rationibus sententiae cotidieque, eu natum debet veniam eum, has ad harum urbanitas. Sumo denique ius ut, has ne harum errem moderatius. Duis habemus philosophia ius ea, cu unum vidisse tritani sea. Sit amet menandri vulputate no, ad pri quis noster eripuit. Dolore ornatus impedit ei pro, nam modo interesset ad.Et qui munere dictas noluisse. Detraxit suavitate eos ad. Ius luptatum mnesarchum ei, no quando vivendo pro. Ad suas atomorum est, cetero diceret duo ea, justo adolescens argumentum nec et.</p>
```

[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pa88zvdu/)

I'm sure it's a simple solution, but I haven't been able to figure it out whilst allowing the text to wrap the image at full size.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what if we put same image after text in paragraph again and show it in media query OR do you want to play with DOM with jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Solution with CSS is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vilaskumkar/pa88zvdu/4/) and with JS is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vilaskumkar/pa88zvdu/7/)

With Css

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    img.right {
        display: none;
    }
    img.right.visible768{
        display: block;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

With JS

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if(viewportWidth <= 768){
        $('.right').appendTo('p');
    }
    else if (viewportWidth >= 769){
        $('.right').prependTo('p');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, would prefer not to have to load the image twice though.

Comment: @Dan So, I guess you would prefer JS one.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pa88zvdu/2/)**

You can position an image at the bottom, with  the help of absolute positioning along with padding bottom(Its value should be equal/greater  than image height)

CSS:

```
p>img {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
    p {
        position:relative;
        height:100%;
        padding-bottom:170px;
    }
    p>img {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left:33%;
    }
```

Comment: Yep, its a good answer, but if you do not know size of the image, its useless TBH.

Answer (score 0):

Is this What you what

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa88zvdu/3/)

HTML

```
<p>
<img class="right" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/matiasam/ios7-style/512/Clear-Tick-icon.png" />
    <span class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex cum utinam nullam equidem, eam an virtute antiopam molestiae. Cum expetendis necessitatibus ea. His iisque conceptam ea, vel novum maiorum ea. Has duis tempor at, quo no elit denique fastidii. Eam justo partiendo te. Diam clita detraxit in pri, copiosae accusata sadipscing te nec. Ad soleat quaerendum pro. Id eos causae eirmod, nec libris quidam commodo cu. Vis et vidit dicam. Ipsum eruditi erroribus eam in, eum lucilius sadipscing omittantur id, aliquam adolescens id nam. Ius deleniti constituam no. Ut dicam ridens pro, qui ea viris scriptorem. Sed ei dicam graeci regione, et placerat suscipiantur has. Solum ridens eu mel. Eius omittam ex per. Summo ancillae ex vim, eam eu case dicit, ei sale primis facete sea. An vix omittam accommodare. An usu rationibus sententiae cotidieque, eu natum debet veniam eum, has ad harum urbanitas. Sumo denique ius ut, has ne harum errem moderatius. Duis habemus philosophia ius ea, cu unum vidisse tritani sea. Sit amet menandri vulputate no, ad pri quis noster eripuit. Dolore ornatus impedit ei pro, nam modo interesset ad.Et qui munere dictas noluisse. Detraxit suavitate eos ad. Ius luptatum mnesarchum ei, no quando vivendo pro. Ad suas atomorum est, cetero diceret duo ea, justo adolescens argumentum nec et.</span>
</p>
```

CSS

```
p {
    display:table;
}
img.right {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    display:block
    display:table-footer-group;
}

span.desc {
    display:table-header-group;
}
```

Comment: here is a [Tutorial](http://www.jtudsbury.com/thoughts/rearrange-div-order.php) for More info

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the image is first and you need tho show it below, you have actually only two options.

Use absolute positioning of image (requires you to know its size), or using pseudo tables (no size od image required).

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/yy98w8rj/1/

Pseudo tables:

```css
.right {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  p {
    display: table;
  }
  .right {
    float: none;
    display: table-footer-group;
  }
  .text {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img class="right" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/matiasam/ios7-style/512/Clear-Tick-icon.png" />
  <span class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex cum utinam nullam equidem, eam an virtute antiopam molestiae. Cum expetendis necessitatibus ea. His iisque conceptam ea, vel novum maiorum ea. Has duis tempor at, quo no elit denique fastidii. Eam justo partiendo te. Diam clita detraxit in pri, copiosae accusata sadipscing te nec. Ad soleat quaerendum pro. Id eos causae eirmod, nec libris quidam commodo cu. Vis et vidit dicam. Ipsum eruditi erroribus eam in, eum lucilius sadipscing omittantur id, aliquam adolescens id nam. Ius deleniti constituam no. Ut dicam ridens pro, qui ea viris scriptorem. Sed ei dicam graeci regione, et placerat suscipiantur has. Solum ridens eu mel. Eius omittam ex per. Summo ancillae ex vim, eam eu case dicit, ei sale primis facete sea. An vix omittam accommodare. An usu rationibus sententiae cotidieque, eu natum debet veniam eum, has ad harum urbanitas. Sumo denique ius ut, has ne harum errem moderatius. Duis habemus philosophia ius ea, cu unum vidisse tritani sea. Sit amet menandri vulputate no, ad pri quis noster eripuit. Dolore ornatus impedit ei pro, nam modo interesset ad.Et qui munere dictas noluisse. Detraxit suavitate eos ad. Ius luptatum mnesarchum ei, no quando vivendo pro. Ad suas atomorum est, cetero diceret duo ea, justo adolescens argumentum nec et.        
    </span>
</p>
```

Absolute positioning:

```css
p img {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  p {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 170px;
  }
  p img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img class="right" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/matiasam/ios7-style/512/Clear-Tick-icon.png" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex cum utinam nullam equidem, eam an virtute antiopam molestiae. Cum expetendis necessitatibus ea. His iisque conceptam ea, vel novum maiorum ea. Has duis tempor at, quo no elit denique fastidii. Eam justo partiendo te. Diam
  clita detraxit in pri, copiosae accusata sadipscing te nec. Ad soleat quaerendum pro. Id eos causae eirmod, nec libris quidam commodo cu. Vis et vidit dicam. Ipsum eruditi erroribus eam in, eum lucilius sadipscing omittantur id, aliquam adolescens id
  nam. Ius deleniti constituam no. Ut dicam ridens pro, qui ea viris scriptorem. Sed ei dicam graeci regione, et placerat suscipiantur has. Solum ridens eu mel. Eius omittam ex per. Summo ancillae ex vim, eam eu case dicit, ei sale primis facete sea.
  An vix omittam accommodare. An usu rationibus sententiae cotidieque, eu natum debet veniam eum, has ad harum urbanitas. Sumo denique ius ut, has ne harum errem moderatius. Duis habemus philosophia ius ea, cu unum vidisse tritani sea. Sit amet menandri
  vulputate no, ad pri quis noster eripuit. Dolore ornatus impedit ei pro, nam modo interesset ad.Et qui munere dictas noluisse. Detraxit suavitate eos ad. Ius luptatum mnesarchum ei, no quando vivendo pro. Ad suas atomorum est, cetero diceret duo ea,
  justo adolescens argumentum nec et.
</p>
```